# OpenCV OCL logical indexing

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, opencl

I am working on an algorithm with many computations done on a GPU. I'm working mainly with oclMat structures and am trying to avoid copying from CPU to GPU and vice versa, yet I cannot find an easy way to:

1. compare all elements in an ocl matrix to a specific single value (be it float or double, for instance) and create a logical matrix in accordance
2. create an oclMat matrix with a given size and type initialized with all elements to a specific value (for example all elements are float and equal to 1.234567)

For example:

```
cv::ocl::oclMat M1 =...
// DO STUFF WITH M1
cv::ocl::oclMat logicalM1 = M1>1.55; // compare directly to a single value
cv::ocl::oclMat logicalM2 = ... ; // i.e. I want a 100x100 CV_32FC1 matrix with all elements set to be equal to 1.234567
```

By reading the documentation, it seems using cv::ocl::compare only works with both matrices the same dimensions and type, so maybe my first request isn't feasible. On the other hand, I don't know how to initialize a specific matrix directly in ocl (with cv::Mat I know how it's done).

I assume an easy workaround exists, but haven't found one yet... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Looks like `cv::ocl::compare` supports only two `cv::oclMat` on input. 
But you can create `oclMat` filled with specific value as follows:

```
cv::ocl::oclMat logicalM2(M1.size(), M1.type);
logicalM2.setTo(cv::Scalar(1.234567));
cv::ocl::oclMat logicalM1;
cv::ocl::compare(M1, logicalM2, logicalM1, cv::CMP_GT);
```

P.S. Also I suggest you trying new OpenCV 3.0 with Transparent-API which makes processing on GPU using OpenCL much easier.

Comment: Excellent answer regarding creating a new matrix! As to OpenCV 3.0 - I know about it, but am waiting for the final release (currently in RC1).

Comment: BTW, OpenCV 3.0 supports compare with scalar.